# Free access to protected member

Tags: java, protected

I create a class, that has a few `protected` members, that are completely accessible to other classes:

```
class MyClass {
    protected String name;
}
```

In my opinion, this shouldn't compile:

```
MyClass mc = new MyClass();
mc.name = "foo";
```

but it works fine. When I make the member `private`, it works as expected. How could this be?

A few notes, but they shouldn't make any difference I think:

- the `mc` is inside a `HashMap`,
- I access it inside an `Activity`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`protected` members are accessible in subclasses(in same or different package) and *all the classes in the same package*. If you move that code to a different package, you would get the expected behaviour.

See [Access Control](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html).

Comment: Well, that explains everything. Thanks. I guess it differs from C#/C++ which is where I learned the concept.

Answer (score 2):

The oracle docs are defining protected as followes:

> The protected modifier specifies that the member can only be accessed within its own package (as with package-private) and, in addition, by a subclass of its class in another package.

See this [Link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)

This means if you move your Class to another package you cannot acces the name.